# Item id null when multiple column total value is 0 in codeigniter framework

Tags: mysql

I write a query for get multiple columns sum value. But when multiple column sum is 0 then my item_id return null. So, my list item can't display thous item.

**My query:**

```
   SELECT
    phppos_sales_items.item_id, IFNULL(SUM(trans_inventory),0) AS Total
FROM
    phppos_sales_items inner join phppos_inventory on phppos_sales_items.item_id = phppos_inventory.trans_items
WHERE
    phppos_inventory.trans_comment LIKE 'RECV %' and phppos_inventory.trans_items in ( '1486')
```

**My result:**

[image]

Comment: Outer joins... LEFT, Right etc...  and where clause which are on the join to the where clause unless on the all records except side.  Simply put: your where clause and choice of join is excluding them.

Comment: try with left join and use IFNULL when you have null value in item_id.

Answer (score 0):

LEFT JOIN

I want all records from phpos_sales_items and only those that match from phppos_inventory

If you leave the where clause, you eliminate the records the left join would keep as "null"

```
SELECT phppos_sales_items.item_id
     , SUM(coalesce(trans_inventory,0)) AS Total
FROM  phppos_sales_items 
LEFT join phppos_inventory 
  on phppos_sales_items.item_id = phppos_inventory.trans_items
 AND phppos_inventory.trans_comment LIKE 'RECV %' 
WHERE phppos_sales_items .trans_items in ( '1486')
```

Comment: then reference phppos_sales_items in ('1486') instead of the other table.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure you'll get results even when there are no matching rows in the other table, use `LEFT JOIN`.

That way, all the results of your first table will be returned and matched to the rows of your second table and, when no results on the second table are matched, the results of the first table will still be returned.

Also, when you need to filter on the *second table*, add the filter in the `JOIN` instead of the `where` clause, so that it won't affect the rows on the *first* table.

For example:

```
SELECT
    phppos_sales_items.item_id,
    IFNULL(SUM(trans_inventory),0) AS Total
FROM phppos_sales_items
LEFT JOIN phppos_inventory ON (
    phppos_sales_items.item_id = phppos_inventory.trans_items
    AND
    phppos_inventory.trans_items in ('1486')
    AND
    phppos_inventory.trans_comment LIKE 'RECV %'
)
```

No `WHERE` clause is needed in your case.